# Selenium does not want to click on the drop-down list

Tags: python, selenium

I need Selenium to click on the drop-down list, but how to do this? There is a nick field, the value "aldassa" is passed there and if it is in the database it suggested to choose from drop-down list. That's the list and you need to click on any of the presented

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDi6h.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

nick=driver.find_element_by_name('yid')
nick.send_keys('aldassa')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nick).click(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desktop-suggestions-container')).perform()
```

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ9al.png)

The error does not produce, but does not want to click. 
I try

```
nick=driver.find_element_by_name('yid')
nick.send_keys('aldassa')
offer_nick = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.desktop-suggestions-container')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nick).click(offer_nick).perform()
```

but there is no result. How to do it right?

Comment: What versions of Firefox & Selenium are you using. Looks like the combination of latest versions of Selenium & Firefox are having "click" issue.

Comment: Firefox 58.0 (64-bit) Selenium (i dont know), but i everything set yesterday

Comment: Name: selenium
Version: 3.8.1

Comment: See this https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1395
Use Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 with Firefox 47.0.1

Comment: this code work with chrome) thx!

Comment: Nice. That confirms "the click issue because of latest versions of Selenium & Firefox".